# How to read in a single keyboard character (like getch)?

Tags: c#, input, getch

In C, I could use getch() for getting an input without having the user to press enter.
e.g.

```
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
    c = getch();
    return 0;
}
```

What function can do the same in C#? (without pressing enter).

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`Console.ReadKey()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Obtains the next character or function key pressed by the user.

It returns information about pressed key. Then you can use [`KeyChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo.keychar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to get Unicode character of pressed key:

```
int Main()
{
    char c = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Console.ReadKey().KeyChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to Read the character from the `Console` without pressing `Enter` key

From MSDN:

> Obtains the next character or function key pressed by the user. The
>   pressed key is displayed in the console window.

Try This:

```
char ch=Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
getch();
```

**does not show** the **input** in the console.

Therefore you need this in C#

```
char ch = Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar;
```

if you need the **input display** at console then this you need

```
char ch1 = Console.ReadKey(false).KeyChar;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get an integer with `Console.Read()`

then you can convert it to a char using `Convert.ToChar(x)`

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx